# Samba shares on dvd Player

Tags: windows-7, debian, samba

Hy

my problem is that i wont find the smb shares from my nas (debian / netgear ready nas) on the samsung bd player. When the NAS is browse master, i only can see the shares from notebook on dvd plaxer. But when the notebook (win 7) is browse master, i can see both shares on dvd player. On notebook i can see whith any configuration, all shares at any time.

My smb.conf

```
[global]
 browseable = 1
 hostname lookups = 1
 os level = 255
 wins support = Yes
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 domain master = Yes
 dns proxy = Yes
 preferred master = Yes
 local master = Yes 
 hostname lookups = 1
 dos charset = CP437
```

The current debug smb debug informations:
http://pastebin.com/PPqdgJnK

Here it seems that the NAS is browse master.
Strange is, that neither with "net view" yet with "nbtstat" have no informations about the DVD player.